Definition of MaxMin strategy

I found this definition of maxmin strategy. Why is the change from $s_2$ to $\sigma_2$ and vice-versa allowed?

What are the definitions of $S_2$ and $\Sigma_2$?

@Henry $S_2$ is the strategy set containing all the pure strategies while $\sum_2$ is the strategy set containing all the mixed strategies of player $2$. (Some books write $\sum_2$ as $\triangle S_2$).

if possible, please tell us where do you see this.

@SiongThyeGoh https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xbrazdil/games_2022_2.pdf Page 349.
